# Mongoengine: Query a MapField

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine, odm

I have a map field that I want to query by. Something like:

```
class User(mongoengine.Document):
    email = mongoengine.EmailField(required=False, unique=False)
    username = mongoengine.StringField(max_length=30, min_length=6, required=True, unique=True)
    password = mongoengine.StringField(max_length=500, min_length=6, required=True)
    profiles = mongoengine.MapField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(DeviceProfile))
```

So in the field, **profiles**, I store the objects like so: *device_id: DeviceProfile object*.

I tried: `User.objects(profiles__device_id=device_id)` to no avail. How do I query so that I only return User objects that have a specific key in the profiles field? Basically, I want to query for User documents that contain a certain DeviceProfile object based on its device ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving this here for anyone else that runs into this problem.

In order to retrieve the Mongoengine document by the key of the map field, you use the `exists` operator. For example, the query can be constructed and then passed to the object method:

```
qry = {
    'profiles__{}__exists'.format(key): True,
    '_cls': 'User'
}

User.object(**qry)
```

Treating the `exists` operator like a "regular" query doesn't work since any non-null, non-zero value will be treated as `True` and the match will return any Documents where there is something in the MapField. For example:

```
Users.object(profiles__exists=key)
```

will return all objects that has a non-empty MapField.